# Cannot make class from XSD file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-serialization

I am having a problem generating a C# class from an existing XSD file. I am using the xsd.exe tool from Visual Studio 2010. I got the official xsd file from the site of the Belgian gouvernment so I do not think the problem is within the xsd file.

This is where my xsd file comes from :

http://financien.belgium.be/nl/E-services/Intervat/xsd-schema_s/

Periodieke aangiften    NewTVA-in_v0_9.xsd (ZIP, 3.77 Kb)

If I try to generate my class I get the following error :

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'Aangifte'. 
   - the datatype '[http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon:Representative_Type](http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon%3aRepresentative_Type)' is missing.

I am quite new to the XML making in C#. Every help is appreciated !

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nsgocev already wrote your schema file is using a type that is described in another schema file. It's quite the same like use a class that is defined in a different assembly.

The class you need can be found also on the very same page. Within the table of version 0.9 is the last entry "Alle schema's" (Xsd-in.zip). Just download that too and put all these files also into the same folder as your schema file. Within the file "IntervatInputCommon_v0_9.xsd" the needed type is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The schema you are trying to use has references another XSD file via the  element which is missing from the provided location. You either need to find the schema somewhere else or download it and fix the reference.

Comment: Why is this referenced to another XSD file? I do not understand the purpose? Can't I just use this XSD file? This is the only one I need I think.

Comment: The other XSD file contains definitions for some types that are used in this one. You can modify the existing XSD to contain the definitions, but you need to get them from the other schema.